# How to display values from google script object in html <p>?

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets, javascript-objects

HTML code

I want to display object values in this form in <p or easier solutions

```
<div class="control-form-id">
  <label for="id">Id:</label>
  <input type="text" name="id" id="id" required>
  <button type="button" onclick="JSinHTML();" id="search" >Search</button>
</div>

<div class="serial">
  <label for="serial">Serial number:</label>
  <p id="serial">result</p>
</div>

<script>
  function JSinHTML(){
     let id_form ={}
  id_form.input = document.getElementById("id").value
  alert(id_form.input);
  google.script.run.main(id_form);
  document.getElementById("id").value = "";
} 
               
                  
</script>
```

GOOGLE SCRIPT code

function findId returns row number by typed id

```
function main(JSinHtml){
    let numberRow = findId(JSinHtml.input); 
    Logger.log("input in main " + JSinHtml.input);
    let toHtml = {};
    toHtml.id = sheet_spis.getRange(numberRow, column_id).getValue();
    toHtml.serial_number = sheet_spis.getRange(numberRow, column_serialnr).getValue();
    toHtml.size = sheet_spis.getRange(numberRow, column_size).getValue();
    toHtml.type = sheet_spis.getRange(numberRow, column_type).getValue();
    Logger.log(toHtml); //I want to display separately this values in few <p>
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your situation, how about the following modification?

#### HTML & Javascript side:

##### From

```
google.script.run.main(id_form);
```

##### To:

```
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(e => {
  document.getElementById("serial").innerHTML = e.serial_number;
}).main(id_form);
```

#### Google Apps Script side:

##### From

```
Logger.log(toHtml); //I want to display separately this values in few <p>
```

##### To:

```
Logger.log(toHtml);
return toHtml;
```

#### Note:

- From `<p id="serial">result</p>`, I guessed that you might have wanted to put the value of `serial_number`. So, I proposed it. If you want to show the whole object of `toHtml`, please modify `document.getElementById("serial").innerHTML = e.serial_number;` to `document.getElementById("serial").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(e);`.

#### Reference:

- [withSuccessHandler(function)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run#withSuccessHandler(Function))